# Intent putExtra is not working

Tags: android

I am writing one test application for keystring

In one module I am writing an intent and broadcasting

Broadcasting part:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MY_ACTION");
broadcastIntent.putExtra("my_key_code", "*#1234589*#");
context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

In receiver I want that string, but i am getting error my_key_code not defined.

Receiver Part:

```
if (intent != null &&    intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.MY_ACTION"))
 {
         if (intent.getStringExtra("my_key_code")
                    .equals(context.getString("*#1234589*#")))
```

Can any one help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to enter your if condition when the value is equal to `*#1234589*#`. If this is the case then your IF condition is wrong

Lets try like this

```
   String xxx = intent.getStringExtra("my_key_code");
    if (xxx.equals("*#1234589*#")){
}
```